# How to register variable from shell command which contains test statement ? (double square brackets)

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to register variable like this:

```
- name: create database password
  shell: chdir=/var/www/website if [[ -n "$WEBSITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD" ]]; then echo "$WEBSITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD";else bundle exec rake secret;fi
  register: db_password
```

When I run this command in shell it works fine, but running it from ansible returns an error:

`"stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found"`

How should I escape it ?

Comment: I suspect `bash` is not default shell on your target host, so `[[` is not available. And, honestly, this task is anti-pattern for Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

sh is the default shell for the shell module. You need to do the following:

```
- name: create database password
  shell: chdir=/var/www/website if [[ -n "$WEBSITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD" ]]; then echo "$WEBSITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD";else bundle exec rake secret;fi
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: db_password
```

However as Konstantin points out, this is not an ideal way to handle what you are trying to do.